# "An object is a member of Object" in ES2017 Specs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

Can anyone help explain "An object is a member of Object" in ES2017 Language Specs? The sentence shows up in the specs multiple times. For example, in Chapter 4.2 ECMAScript Overview

> Properties are containers that hold other objects, primitive values,
>   or functions. A primitive value is a member of one of the following
>   built-in types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, String, and Symbol;
>   **an object is a member of the built-in type Object;** and a function is a callable object. A function that is associated with an object via
>   a property is called a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is a language made up of objects. object({}) is not the only type of Object. Arrays, functions, maps are all *type of* Object, expect for the primitives mentioned in the spec all are type of Object. The term

> an object is a member of the built-in type Object

means that regular object({}) is part of the primitive built in type Object (notice the difference in caps and smalls). you can continue to say

function is a member of the built-in type Object,
Array is part of and so on..

Comment: There are no different types of objects in the specification. There is only the Object type.

Comment: I agree corrected my wordings. Apologies if they were not exact i was just trying to make the OP understand the difference between object and Object.

Answer (score 2):

It's a specification. It defines things like these, and states that EcmaScript uses different [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93token_distinction), "[sets of data values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type)" if you want. Then it goes on to define that

- we call one of these types the *Object type* (notice the capital *O* - it's always used when referring to the type and not the ordinary term "object" or the `Object` constructor function)
- we call the members of this particular type *objects*.